# Angular - Display 5 objects on the screen at a time with delay

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a REST service call that returns ~24 records.  I would like to display 5 of those at a time on my view and cycle through every 10 seconds.  Below is one of my attempts, but this doesn't work...

```
this.http.get<HomeListing[]>(`/api/HomeListing`).subscribe(z => {

  const totalCount = z.length;
  const pageSize: number = 5;
  let currentPage: number = 1;
  let endPoint = pageSize;
  let exitLoop: boolean = false;

  while (true) {
    if (currentPage * pageSize > totalCount) {
      endPoint = totalCount % pageSize;
      exitLoop = true;
    } else if (currentPage * pageSize === totalCount) {
      exitLoop = true;
    }
    this.homeListings = z.slice((currentPage - 1) * pageSize, endPoint);

    currentPage++;
    if (exitLoop)
      break;
  }
});
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I didn't misunderstand your requirement then you have got to get the elements of an array in chunks of "5" and in an interval of 10 seconds. I achieved it with this approach, have a look:

```
export class AppComponent  {

  arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]

  startNewTimer = new Subject();

  maxImagestoDisplay: number = 5;

  slideInterval: number = 10000;

  sub: Subscription

  ngOnInit() {

    let maxCycle = Math.trunc(this.arr.length / this.maxImagestoDisplay);

    this.sub = this.startNewTimer.pipe(switchMap( (startVal: number) =>
      timer(startVal, this.slideInterval)
    ),tap(data => {
      if (data >= maxCycle) {
        this.startNewTimer.next(this.slideInterval)
      }
    })).subscribe(timerIndex => {
      console.log(this.arr.slice(timerIndex * this.maxImagestoDisplay, (timerIndex + 1 ) * this.maxImagestoDisplay));
    })

    this.startNewTimer.next(0)

  }
}
```

There is a timer running in this code which resets (destroyed and a new one is created) itself after all the elements have been spawned.
Have a look if you can fit it for your requirement, see an example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oo3xas?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Can't thank you enough!  I'll attempt to implement today.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: I would like to loop the rest call, so basically when I start back at the beginning, get a new list of data.  You see an easy way to do that?  Should I post a new question?

Comment: @dascalos From what I understand, you want to do an API call to fetch the a new list of data once the current list is over. The problem with this is the time taken by the API call to be over, this will give some timing issues in cycling. See this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emjbjd?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I retooled things a bit and came up with this... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uajexv  So instead of the recurring timer pulse, I trigger it manually each time.